# Update Model from Database always shows tables under Add in EF 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have an existing MVC3 project using EF4 with a database first design. All entities and the edmx were generated correctly.

The problem is when I add a column to a table or make any change to my database. After making a change, I would go back to VS2010 and open my edmx file.  When I right click and select "Update Model from Database" it shows all my tables under "Add" instead of showing only the changes I have made under "refresh".  I have searched everywhere to find a reason for this but to no avail.  Any help would be great.